# Does using a headless browser with rselenium significanly faster?

Tags: r, selenium, phantomjs, rselenium

I'd like to know if using a headless browser, (such as [phantomJS](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-headless.html)) with RSelenium significanly faster than running scripts with a regular browser (such as chrome)? Also driving it directly or using a selenium server ?

Is there a short function to check/plot difference in speeds?

Comment: Run the benchmark yourself.

Comment: Any idea how, the RSelenium package has a scant documentation on benchmarking.

Comment: Use  the tools that R gives you to measure time.

Comment: In PhantomJS you can implement resource listeners. Basically, you start timer when you open your url, and you wait for the last resource to load, and stop the timer. The problems are with AJAX requests, then you have to listen for specific `div` to load etc.